# The Longest Character In UTF-8

Tags: character, width

What is the character with the most width? So "|" would have less width than "a", any ideas? Maybe a program could do this? Or maybe you just know a really widthy character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In UTF-8 The longest character is '﷽' as of the post of this comment, not sure what you needed it for but hope I helped

Comment: Interesting, how did you know this?

Comment: From a previous coding challenge I was asked to examine the length of all UTF-8 characters. After searching through all of them, this was the longest one.

Comment: @MaxCoates If you do have the code for the same, can you add in a small snippet of how you proceeded with the task? It would be really helpful to know how you derived the longest character.

Comment: It’s 2022… `"﷽"` is code point [U+FDFD](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=FDFD) which is a three-byte encoded character `'\xef\xb7\xbd'`. Taking a skin-toned emoji, e.g. `"‍♂️"` is seventeen bytes: `'\xf0\x9f\xa4\xa6\xf0\x9f\x8f\xbb\xe2\x80\x8d\xe2\x99\x82\xef\xb8\x8f'`. But I haven’t noodled through all valid Unicode characters recently…

Answer (score 9):

There is also this thing.
ௌௌௌௌௌௌௌௌௌௌௌௌௌௌௌௌௌௌௌௌௌௌௌ
Yes, that's one character, although some systems may treat it as more or omit parts of it.

Comment: What’s that string’s Unicode code point?

Comment: It seems to be made up of repetitions of [U+0BCC](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=0BCC) - maybe a weird ligature or somesuch?